# Did the Ministry of Magic ever employ muggles?

Tags: harry-potter, ministry-of-magic

Do we know if the Ministry ever employed Muggles to do anything, either on a contract or part time basis? I am talking about actual *paid* work, where the Muggle may or may not know he is working for the Ministry, and he may or may not be obliviated afterwards.

I remember that a Muggle was employed to manage the incoming guests at the Quidditch World Cup camp site, but I don't know if that would count as the Ministry directly employing him, rather than just the World Cup management committee. If it is indeed the Ministry it can be included in the answer, along with any other examples.

Comment: and the implications of enchanting the muggle campground owner....the ministry may clutch their pearls at Voldemort / Death Eaters, but they aren't much better...

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn’t say the Ministry employed the Muggles at the World Cup. Rather, the Muggles were offering (haha) their land as lodging. Think of it as a company using a hotel for a conference. The company employees (wizards) still pay the hotel (Muggles) for meals and lodging even though it’s through the company.

As for actually employing Muggles, I can’t think of any examples from the books. There doesn’t really seem to be a need for them. It’s probably a liability when it comes to the International Statute of Secrecy, if it’s not an outright violation. I think there’s also be a prejudice against using Muggles from people like Fudge and Dolores in the Ministry.

Comment: Muggle family members are allowed to know about the Wizarding World without being subjected to memory removal. They can even visit Diagon Alley and Hogwarts

Comment: I've wondered the same about the Hogwarts express - here we have wizards operating Muggle machinery, or do humans do it?